# Databricks, Unity Catalog, Volumes, External location and misconfigurations

Tags: configuration, permissions, databricks

Let me start with the things that works:

```
%sql show volumes
```

returns empty answer

```
%sql show external location
```

returns 1 entry, I have a name and a URL. Let's say that the name is "pippo". This name is bound to a s3 bucket, and I think that is correct.

At this point, how should I access the external location?

I issued a

```
%python dbutils.fs.mounts()
```

And I got:

```
[MountInfo(mountPoint='/databricks-datasets', source='databricks-datasets', encryptionType=''),
 MountInfo(mountPoint='/Volumes', source='UnityCatalogVolumes', encryptionType=''),
 MountInfo(mountPoint='/databricks/mlflow-tracking', source='databricks/mlflow-tracking', encryptionType='sse-kms'),
 MountInfo(mountPoint='/databricks-results', source='databricks-results', encryptionType='sse-kms'),
 MountInfo(mountPoint='/databricks/mlflow-registry', source='databricks/mlflow-registry', encryptionType='sse-kms'),
 MountInfo(mountPoint='/Volume', source='DbfsReserved', encryptionType=''),
 MountInfo(mountPoint='/volumes', source='DbfsReserved', encryptionType=''),
 MountInfo(mountPoint='/', source='DatabricksRoot', encryptionType='sse-kms'),
 MountInfo(mountPoint='/volume', source='DbfsReserved', encryptionType='')]
```

Now, In my understanding, the external locations should be available under /Volumes

the current catalog in `main`, and the current schema is `default`:

```
%python dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/Volumes/main/default/pippo")
```

I got

```
AnalysisException: [UC_VOLUME_NOT_FOUND] Volume `main`.`default`.`pippo` does not exist. Please use 'SHOW VOLUMES' to list available volumes.
```

When I  try to create VOLUME

```
%sql CREATE external VOLUME my_bucket 
LOCATION 's3://bucket_name_as_reported_by_show_volumes'
```

I get:

```
com.databricks.sql.managedcatalog.acl.UnauthorizedAccessException: PERMISSION_DENIED: User does not have CREATE VOLUME on Schema 'main.default'.
```

At this point, it seems a serious misconfiguration problem. Am I wrong?

Comment: What's your goal?

Comment: @Kashyap my goal is to read the CSV that will be put on the bucket. However, it seems that there is no way to address the bucket...

Comment: An external location is a reference to an S3 bucket where you can place Unity Catalog resources in (Catalog, Schema, Table, Volume). Default the Volume gets the storage location of the Catalog, unless you override it.

Comment: @ozw1z5rd, you are not mandated to create a VOLUME, to read from S3. Also I don't see anywhere in your post an attempt to read a csv from S3. If you add it, I can respond. Otherwise, as someone pointed out, the error msg you get for doing what you're doing, is pretty clear and explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, your user does not have the `CREATE VOLUME` permission on the schema `default` in the `catalog` main.

However, Unity Catalog has privilege inheritance (https://docs.databricks.com/en/data-governance/unity-catalog/manage-privileges/index.html#privilege-inheritance), which leads me to guess that you have permission to use something like the catalog/schema `main.foo`, but you do not have permission to use catalog/schema `main.default`.

If your permissions were set in the catalog `main`, then the permissions would be inherited to all schemas in that catalog.

Comment: Actually, I can read tables under main.default. Not sure if this changes something.

Comment: Can you create volumes anywhere else? The inheritance model still applies and I am still assuming your issue is that you have different schema permissions